# What can I put in $x$ of Lorentz transformation?

Tags: special-relativity, coordinate-systems, inertial-frames

[image]

Can I put "x = ct" in the red x?

Comment: It's not clear exactly what you want to know. $(t,x,y,z)$ are the coordinates in the unprimed frame of some event. If a flash of light is emitted at the origin at $t=0$ then $x=ct$ tells you the $x$ coordinate of that light for all $t \ge 0$.